# How to convert value of difftime from hours to days?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have dataframe which looks like.

```
structure(list(format_date = c("Feb-21 (W5)", "Mar-21 (W1)", 
"Mar-21 (W2)"), Total_count = c(53L, 1079L, 1288L), Count_Diff_1 = c(29L, 
508L, 519L), Count_Diff_2 = c(22L, 505L, 624L), Count_Diff_3 = c(2L, 
66L, 145L), Average_Diff_1 = structure(c(10.3464846743295, 6.03846784776903, 
2.75151412973667), class = "difftime", units = "hours"), Average_Diff_2 = structure(c(6.46958333333333, 
7.78101430143014, 2.58788906695157), class = "difftime", units = "hours"), 
    Average_Diff_3 = structure(c(162.45419129418, 133.452629846369, 
    54.3061989570153), class = "difftime", units = "hours"), 
    Per_Diff_1 = c(0.547169811320755, 0.470806302131603, 0.402950310559006
    ), Per_Diff_2 = c(0.415094339622642, 0.468025949953661, 0.484472049689441
    ), Per_Diff_3 = c(0.0377358490566038, 0.0611677479147359, 
    0.112577639751553)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), groups = structure(list(
    format_date = c("Feb-21 (W5)", "Mar-21 (W1)", "Mar-21 (W2)"
    ), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to convert the values in days if it is >24 hours in `Average_1`,`Average_2` and `Average_3` column  and covert the `Per_Diff_1`,`Per_Diff_2` and `Per_Diff_3` with percentage 2 decimal point with % sign.

Also, it would be great if somehow I can mange to order the `format_date` in descending order. Right now it is coming as `Feb-21 (W5)`, `Mar-21 (W1)` and `Mar-21 (W2)` it should be `Mar-21 (W2)`,`Mar-21 (W1)` and `Feb-21 (W5)`.

Required df<-

```
format_date   Total_count Count_Diff_1 Count_Diff_2 Count_Diff_3 Average_1    Average_2    Average_3 Per_Diff_1 Per_Diff_2 Per_Diff_3
Feb-21 (W5)    53         29           22           2            10.34 hours  6.46 hours   6.7 Days  54.71%     41.50%     3.77%
```

Comment: @akrun: The expected conversion is whenever `hours` exceed 24 in any of the average column it should show in Days. For Example, `162.66625 hours` to `6.77 Days`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply change `units` of the difftime class to days in a case handling using `if`. For the percentages try `formatC`.

```
d[6:8] <- lapply(d[6:8], function(x) {if (all(x > 24)) units(x) <- "days";round(x, 2)})
d[9:11] <- lapply(d[9:11], function(x) paste0(formatC(x*100, 1, format="f"), "%"))
d <- d[order(d$format_date, decreasing=T), ]
```

### Result

```
d
#   format_date Total_count Count_Diff_1 Count_Diff_2 Count_Diff_3 Average_Diff_1
# 3 Mar-21 (W2)        1288          519          624          145     2.75 hours
# 2 Mar-21 (W1)        1079          508          505           66     6.04 hours
# 1 Feb-21 (W5)          53           29           22            2    10.35 hours
#   Average_Diff_2 Average_Diff_3 Per_Diff_1 Per_Diff_2 Per_Diff_3
# 3     2.59 hours      2.26 days      40.3%      48.4%      11.3%
# 2     7.78 hours      5.56 days      47.1%      46.8%       6.1%
# 1     6.47 hours      6.77 days      54.7%      41.5%       3.8%
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `across` on the columns that `starts_with` 'Average' to convert the values if it is greater than 24 then divide by 24, append 'Days' as suffix, or else return by appending 'hours' as suffix.  Similarly, the columns that `starts_with` 'Per' can be formatted to percentage with `label_percent` from `scales`.  Then, we `arrange` the 'format_date' in `desc`ending order after conversion to `yearmon` class (from `zoo::as.yearmon`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(scales)
df1 %>%
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('Average'), 
     ~ case_when(as.numeric(.) > 24 ~ str_c(round(as.numeric(.)/24, 2),
    ' Days'),
      TRUE ~ str_c(as.character(round(., 2)), ' hours'))),
      across(starts_with('Per'), label_percent())) %>%
   arrange(desc(zoo::as.yearmon(str_remove(format_date, '\\s+.*'), '%b-%y')),
          desc(readr::parse_number(str_remove_all(format_date, '.*\\(|\\)'))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 11
#  format_date Total_count Count_Diff_1 Count_Diff_2 Count_Diff_3 Average_Diff_1 Average_Diff_2 Average_Diff_3 Per_Diff_1 Per_Diff_2 Per_Diff_3
#  <chr>             <int>        <int>        <int>        <int> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
#1 Mar-21 (W2)        1288          519          624          145 2.75 hours     2.59 hours     2.26 Days      40.3%      48.4%      11.3%     
#2 Mar-21 (W1)        1079          508          505           66 6.04 hours     7.78 hours     5.56 Days      47.1%      46.8%      6.1%      
#3 Feb-21 (W5)          53           29           22            2 10.35 hours    6.47 hours     6.77 Days      54.7%      41.5%      3.8%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. Just one more help if I can order the `format_date` column in descending order.

Comment: @SophiaWilson I guess the update should help.

Comment: yes, It worked. only the weeks are not in order. Ideally `Mar-21 (W2) ` should be the first row.

Comment: @SophiaWilson I guess this update should work for you